# Pointing out shortcomings in comments

Tags: discussion, comments

In [fast way to replace characters in file ignoring comment lines](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17276683/96588), @anubhava wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17276808/96588) but *also* indirectly [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17276683/fast-way-to-replace-characters-in-file-ignoring-comment-lines/17276861?noredirect=1#comment25046126_17276861) a shortcoming in [@umlaeute's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17276861/96588). I pointed out how to fix the shortcoming without realizing that @anubhava already had written an answer which avoided the issue, and got a reply pointing that out. At that point I was tempted to point out that it would be better if @anubhava had replaced

> What if commented line has few leading spaces before `#` ?

with an assertion like

> This solution won't be able to handle leading spaces.

, perhaps with a link to the relevant answer. What is the best practice in such cases? Arguments:

- I guess non-developers would see the latter as too direct coming from a stranger, but directness (not implying rudeness) is a great feature of Stack Overflow, and kind of native to the developer mindset.
- Even though @anubhava's answer was first *and* seems to be better and simpler than @umlaeute's, when I first saw the question they both had the same score. @anubhava's answer probably would not have received the score it deserved if the shortcomings had not been pointed out.
- Some people are more comfortable with directness than others. Would it be sensible to encourage directness in such cases, or would it result in more unwanted behaviour?
- I often find the Socratic method is more likely to make people agree than just asserting something, even if it's easily verifiable.
- A bunch of back and forth because of the missing assertion means more noise in the comments.

Comment: I prefer using the latter. Ideally, suggest a fix as well.

Comment: I don't see a problem with either comment.  Leading questions can be quite effective at making a point, so long as you're sufficiently clear, which that one is (in my opinion).

Comment: So what was your comment? Why did you delete it?

Comment: @doubleDown I pointed out one way to fix umlaeute's answer, but I deleted it when I realized it was redundant after reading anubhava's answer.

Comment: @l0b0, I don't think you should have deleted it. umlaeute gets a notification when you comment on how to improve his answer, but he doesn't get a notification when someone else's answer fixes his question.